# Loop through arrays and compare timestamps

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have two arrays that I like to loop through and compare the dates between each array.

```
$newArray = Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [date] => 26-11-2013 9:30:56 PM
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 30-11-2013 11:20:12 AM
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [date] => 26-11-2013 9:30:56 PM
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [id] => 4
            [date] => 30-11-2013 11:20:12 AM
        )
}

$oldArray = Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [date] => 26-11-2013 9:30:56 PM
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [date] => 26-11-2013 9:30:56 PM
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [date] => 26-11-2013 9:30:56 PM
        )
}

foreach ($newArray as $newPhoto) {
    foreach ($oldArray as $oldPhoto) {
        if (strtotime($newPhoto['date']) != strtotime($oldPhoto['date'])) {
            // download new photo
        }
    }
}
```

I realize that placing the `foreach` with a `foreach` is not going to cut it. What is the best way to loop through each of these arrays and compare the dates?

The `$newArray` has the latest photos and compares with the `$oldArray` if the timestamps do not match or there is a new one in the list, download the new images.

In the example, I would be downloading the second and fourth images and ignoring the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this. It does not make any assumptions about the indices of either array, and will be still be fairly efficient as `$oldArray` grows in size.

```
// index $oldArray by id for speed
$index = array();
foreach ($oldArray as $photo) {
    $index[$photo['id']] = $photo['date'];
}

// iterate through new photos, checking if each one needs downloading
foreach ($newArray as $photo) {
    if (!isset($index[$photo['id']]) // photo is not in $oldArray
            || strtotime($photo['date']) > strtotime($index[$photo['id']])) { // photo is in $oldArray, but a new version is available
        // download new photo
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I like this solution. It addresses my assumption of the arrays being key'd the same.

Comment: Thank very much, I will give these a try.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I have a trial run on your above solution.. You rock! Thank you very much for this wonderful solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($newArray as $key => $newPhoto) {
    //If the key doesn't exist in $oldArray it is new
    if(!isset($oldArray[$key])){
      //download new photo
    }
    elseif (strtotime($newPhoto['date']) != strtotime($oldArray[$key]['date'])) { //timestamp mismatch
      //download new photo
    }
}
```

Note: I assume that your oldArray and newArray are keyed the same. I.e if id 1 is in the `0` spot of newArray I assume that id 1 is in the `0` spot in oldArray.

Answer (score 0):

Why use foreach, you can simply use for:

```
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($newArray); $i++){
    if(strtotime($newArray[$i]['date']) != strtotime($oldArray[$i]['date'])){
        //new photo do sth
    }else {
        //old photo do sth or not :)
    }
}
```